# SonarQube Nullpointer on analysis, missing fields or rules parameters

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.5

I'm running into a nullpointer exception when running analysis on a java project.

The condition that triggers the analysis failure only happens when I activate certain Rules in the Quality Profile. Particularly, any rule that has a parameter you can override, causes the nullpointer failure. It fails whether or not I provide an override value or if the parameter is left default.

I should note that I can get *successful* analysis to complete if those particular rules are deactivated in the quality profile. It only seems to be related to certain rules that have parameters.

I can replicate this Nullpointer failure with both the sonar-runner, and the org.sonarqube gradle plugin (v 1.0). So I suspect it is not a problem with the runner or the plugin but some kind of setup issue with the SonarQube server and/or database.

The problem is, I don't know how to go in and fix this issue. The SonarQube database isn't documented (that I'm aware) I suspect that there is something maybe missing in the database but I'm not even sure where they might be.

Any suggestions on where I might look?

Versions:
SonarQube 4.5.2
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.8.0_40 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Mac OS X 10.10.4 x86_64

Here is the stack trace of the error:

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1:43.316s
Final Memory: 27M/635M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sonar.api.batch.rule.Checks.getField(Checks.java:180)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.rule.Checks.configureFields(Checks.java:167)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.rule.Checks.instantiate(Checks.java:152)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.rule.Checks.addAnnotatedChecks(Checks.java:127)
    at org.sonar.java.SonarComponents.registerTestCheckClasses(SonarComponents.java:128)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:82)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:119)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:194)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:233)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:221)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:125)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:173)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: From the error, its more likely to be a problem with a plugin. Which plugins do you have installed. Which is(are) the one related to the Rules you activate to reproduce the error?

Comment: This sounds likes an issue in the java plugin. Can you tell us which version of the java plugin you are using ? Can you try with the latest version (3.4) ?

Comment: Thanks for the response, here are the installed plugins: 
[Java [java] 3.3 SonarQube rule engine]
[Checkstyle [checkstyle] 2.3]
[Clover [clover] 3.0] [Cobertura [cobertura] 1.6.3] [Findbugs [findbugs] 3.2] [Java [java] 3.3] [JIRA [jira] 1.2] [LDAP [ldap] 1.4] [PMD [pmd] 2.3]

Comment: Some examples of the rules that trigger the failure are ["switch" statements should not have too many "case" clauses (default value 30)] or [Classes should not be too complex (Default value 200)]. I am going to try the latest version that you suggested.

Comment: Upgrading the Java plugin didn't do the trick, but downgrading did. It was definitely a problem with the plugin version. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

We solved the problem, and the problem was indeed the Java plugin on the SonarQube server. The solution was to downgrade the Java plugin though. Here are the versions we ended up using:

- Checkstyle [checkstyle]   2.2 Analyze Java code with Checkstyle.
- Clover [clover]   3.0 Get code coverage with Atlassian Clover.
- Cobertura [cobertura] 1.6.3   Get code coverage with Cobertura.
- Findbugs [findbugs]   3.1 Analyze Java code with Findbugs 3.0.0.
- Java [java]   2.9.1   SonarQube rule engine.
- JIRA [jira]   1.2 Connects SonarQube to Atlassian JIRA in various ways.
- LDAP [ldap]   1.4 Delegates authentication to LDAP.
- PMD [pmd] 2.3 Analyze Java code with PMD.